# How To Get Input and Select Values From Table Properly?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dom

I have a lectures table that is empty at first, but when the user clicks the add lecture button, it generates a new row using this function. Here is the event listener for adding rows:

```
  const addLectureScoreBtn = document.getElementById("add-lecture-score-btn");
  addLectureScoreBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const lectureScoresTable = document.getElementById("lecture-score-table");
    const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    const lectureNameCell = document.createElement("td");
    const lectureNameSelect = document.createElement("select");
    lectureNameSelect.id = "lecture-name";
    lectureNameSelect.name = "lecture-name";
    lectures.forEach((lecture) => {
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = lecture.name;
      option.text = lecture.name;
      lectureNameSelect.add(option);
    });
    console.log(lectureNameSelect)
    
    lectureNameCell.appendChild(lectureNameSelect);
    newRow.appendChild(lectureNameCell);

    const midtermCell = document.createElement("td");
    const midtermInput = document.createElement("input");
    midtermCell.appendChild(midtermInput);
    midtermInput.type = "number";
    midtermInput.value = 0;
    midtermInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
        if (midtermInput.value < 0 || midtermInput.value > 100) {
          midtermInput.value = 0;
        }
    });

  newRow.appendChild(midtermCell);
  const finalCell = document.createElement("td");
  const finalInput = document.createElement("input");
  finalInput.type = "number";
  finalInput.value = 0;
  finalCell.appendChild(finalInput);
  newRow.appendChild(finalCell);
  lectureScoresTable.appendChild(newRow);
  const actionsCell = document.createElement("td");
  const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
  deleteBtn.type = "button";
  deleteBtn.textContent = "Delete";
  deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", () => deleteRow(newRow));
  actionsCell.appendChild(deleteBtn);
  newRow.appendChild(actionsCell);
  });
```

After user creates table with grades and selection of lectures, they click save button, when save button clicked, an item like this should be created and added to the students array that was already defined

```
//it is just an example object
const exampleStudent = {
id:'123456'
name:'John'
surname:'Doe'
lectures: [
{
lecture:{code:'2332',name:'Web Development'}, //Whole lecture object
midterm:40,
final:50 }]
```

The problem is most likely here in the createStudent() function, i have tried several methods, but apparently, none of the rows of the table is identified by the code, all of their values are undefined. Here is a version of what i tried already:

```
function createStudent() {
  // create a new student object
  const student = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    lectures: [], //push lecture object
    gpa: 0
  };
  //get id from input
  const studentId = document.getElementById('student-id');
  const studentName = document.getElementById('student-name');
  const studentSurname = document.getElementById('student-surname');
  const lectureScoresTable = document.getElementById("lecture-score-table");
  lectureScoresTable.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((row) => {
    const lectureName = row.querySelectorAll('lecture-name');
    
    const midterm = row.querySelector('#midterm');
    const final = row.querySelector('#final');
    const lecture = {
      lecture: lectures.find((lecture) => lecture.name === lectureName.value),
      midterm: midterm.value,
      final: final.value
    };
    student.lectures.push(lecture);
  }
  );
  student.id = studentId.value;
  student.name = studentName.value;
  student.surname = studentSurname.value;
  student.gpa = calculateGPA(student.lectures);
  //TODO
}
```

This code throws an error that says, cannot read properties of null
PS: Please do not respond in JQuery or any other frameworks, services, i am only using vanilla js html and css

Comment: The `createStrudent` method refers to DOM Elements that are not shown in the rest of the code you posted.  For example, there is no element evident with the `id` "student-id".  Going just by what is presented in the question this does not work because it's trying to manipulate DOM elements that simply do not exist.  Did you mean to set the `id` attribute on something in your dynamic table?  When asking for help debuggiing you must supply a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this suits your needs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Id</label> <input id="student-id" type="text" />
    <br />
    <label>Name</label> <input id="student-name" type="text" />
    <br />
    <label>Surname</label> <input id="student-surname" type="text" />
    <br />

    <button id="add-lecture-score-btn">Add Lecture</button>

    <table id="lecture-score-table"></table>

    <button id="create-student-btn">Create Student</button>

    <script>
      const lectures = [
        { code: "2332", name: "Web Development" },
        { code: "2339", name: "Databases" },
        { code: "5332", name: "Project Managing" },
        { code: "8332", name: "Requirement Elicitation" },
      ];

      const calculateGPA = () => {
        //TODO
        return "GPA";
      };

      document.getElementById("add-lecture-score-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        const lectureScoresTable = document.getElementById("lecture-score-table");
        const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        const lectureNameCell = document.createElement("td");
        const lecturesSelect = document.createElement("select");
        lecturesSelect.classList.add("lectures");

        const selectOption = document.createElement("option");
        selectOption.value = "";
        selectOption.text = " - Select - ";
        lecturesSelect.add(selectOption);
        lectures.forEach((lecture) => {
          const option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = lecture.code;
          option.text = lecture.name;
          lecturesSelect.add(option);
        });
        lectureNameCell.appendChild(lecturesSelect);

        newRow.appendChild(lectureNameCell);

        const midtermCell = document.createElement("td");
        const midtermInput = document.createElement("input");
        midtermInput.type = "number";
        midtermInput.value = 0;
        midtermInput.classList.add("midterm");
        midtermCell.appendChild(midtermInput);
        midtermInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
          if (midtermInput.value < 0 || midtermInput.value > 100) {
            midtermInput.value = 0;
          }
        });

        newRow.appendChild(midtermCell);

        const finalCell = document.createElement("td");
        const finalInput = document.createElement("input");
        finalInput.type = "number";
        finalInput.value = 0;
        finalInput.classList.add("final");
        finalCell.appendChild(finalInput);

        newRow.appendChild(finalCell);

        lectureScoresTable.appendChild(newRow);

        const actionsCell = document.createElement("td");
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
        deleteBtn.type = "button";
        deleteBtn.textContent = "Delete";
        deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", () => newRow.remove());

        actionsCell.appendChild(deleteBtn);
        newRow.appendChild(actionsCell);
      });

      const exampleStudent = {
        id: "123456",
        name: "John",
        surname: "Doe",
        lectures: [
          {
            lecture: { code: "2332", name: "Web Development" }, //Whole lecture object
            midterm: 40,
            final: 50,
          },
        ],
      };

      document.getElementById("create-student-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        const student = {
          id: 0,
          name: "",
          surname: "",
          lectures: [],
          gpa: 0,
        };

        student.id = document.getElementById("student-id").value;
        student.name = document.getElementById("student-name").value;
        student.surname = document.getElementById("student-surname").value;

        document
          .getElementById("lecture-score-table")
          .querySelectorAll("tr")
          .forEach((row) => {
            const lectureId = row.querySelector(".lectures").value;

            const lecture = {
              lecture: lectures.find((lecture) => lecture.code == lectureId),
              midterm: row.querySelector(".midterm").value,
              final: row.querySelector(".final").value,
            };
            student.lectures.push(lecture);
          });

        student.gpa = calculateGPA(student.lectures);
        //TODO

        console.log(student);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you but it still fails to get the values of input fields and select boxes, it is null, why do you think that happens? It is like impossible, i tried anything!

Comment: HI, you copied and pasted the code of the answer and it didn't work?  
I got the object with all the values: https://prnt.sc/OuG7jLk6CQWT

Comment: Oh, I see, I did not copy and paste, only modified relevant pieces according to your approach, I must have missed something when I tried your code only it works but when I try the modified version, it gives an error. Thanks for the answer, it solves my problem, i think i get it :)

Comment: Hey I understand where I did wrong, when I try to add default header rows to the table using HTML, it tries the get the values of them on the for loop and it causes an error, I simply fixed this problem by adding `if (row.rowIndex == 0) return` to the first line of the for loop